# Get all attributes of enclosing function

Tags: python-3.x

Given the following:

```
def outer(msg):
    def inner():
        print(msg)

    return inner

returned_func = outer("Hello")
print(returned_func)
inner_func()
```

Returns the following:

```
<function outer.<locals>.inner at 0x7fe75ad9b670>
Hello
```

**Questions**:

1. Why when `dir(outer)` is called (see below), the `inner` function is missing?
2. How do I access `inner` as an attribute of `outer`?

I.e.

```
dir(outer)

['__annotations__',
 '__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__closure__',
 '__code__',
 '__defaults__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__get__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__globals__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__kwdefaults__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__name__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__qualname__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
```

Comment: `inner` isn't an attribute of `outer`. Why do you expect it to be? It's what's _returned_ by `outer`.

Comment: It's not *only* returned by `outer`, it's also enclosed by `outer`. So why isn't it listed as an attribute of outer, (such as with class methods)?

Comment: Because that's not how locals work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with functions, you must set their attributes explicitely:

```py
def outer():
    def inner():
        return "Hello"

    # Define its attribute `inner`
    outer.inner = inner

    return inner() + " World"

print(outer())    # Outputs Hello World
print(outer.inner())    # Outputs Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a function inside of another function will not give you access to that function because the inner function is inside the *local* scope of the enclosing function. Think of it this way:

```
def foo():
    n = 10
```

The function `inner` in your example is `n` in the example above. In Python, functions function a lot like variables. They can be passed around, returned, etc. In this example, do you think we should be able to access `n` by saying `foo.n`?

> So why isn't it listed as an attribute of outer, (such as with class methods)?

This is totally different from a class declaration; instead, it is one example of higher order functions. It can be classified as such because one function returns another function.